# USB to Ethernet adapter supporting multiple VLANs

Tags: laptop, usb, ethernet

I've tried to "upgrade" my Windows 8.1 Dell Precision M4700 to Windows 10, but Intel Ethernet chipset 82579LM does not support multiple VLANs in Windows 10.

I'm looking for an USB to Ethernet adapter that supports multiple VLANs and has a working Windows 10 driver.

Is somebody using this kind of adapter?